# ASP.NET Identity record user registration and last logged on time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

I'm migrating an ASP.NET website from the old Membership provider to ASP.NET Identity 2

I noticed that user registration and last logged on time are not recorded with the new provider. Is there a way to customizing the code to do that?

Comment: For inserting time you can use `trigger` at the back end by using insert and update trigger.

Comment: that's a database function right?

Comment: Yes.You need to add Trigger inside your table name.When a new row will insert this trigger will call automatically and fill current date and time into  the particular column.I can send you the trigger syntax as well..

Comment: is there a way to do this by modifying/extending asp.net identity code?

Comment: Trigger is not the best way to do this.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To capture registration date and last login date you'll need to extend user object:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     public virtual DateTime? LastLoginTime { get; set; }
     public virtual DateTime? RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

And then on user creation, you'll have to populate `RegistrationDate` field. And on every successful login you'll have to update `LastLoginTime`.

And no, Identity does not support these fields automatically, you'll have to work around your requirements yourself.

Comment: I suggest a nullable DateTimeOffset.

Comment: hi @trailmax, how to locate 'on every successful login' ?

Comment: @OhMyDog `PasswordSignInAsync` [method](PasswordSignInAsync) returns object [SignInStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.owin.signinstatus(v=vs.108).aspx). If the value is set to be `Success` - you know you are onto something.

Comment: @trailmax SignInManager<TUser, TKey> got it, thank you so much