# Setting a user detail in Login.cshtml.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

### **Edit for clarity:**

`user.LastActiveDate` in **Login.cshtml.cs** is successfully getting the data from the user ([Screenshot showing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7E9s.jpg)), but I am unable to actually change the data of `LastActiveDate` to current date.

**Original Question:**

I have set up **AspNetCore.Identity.UI** and have set up Login and Registration through it. As soon as the user logs in, I am trying to set up a detail *LastActiveDate*, which would contain `DateTime.UtcNow`, which should be set as soon as the user logs in.

What I've tried is setting this in the `if(result.Succeeded)`, however this doesn't seem to be working. Any idea on what I might be doing wrong/idea on how I should be doing this?

*Login.cshtml.cs*

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    //THIS NEEDS TO SET LastActiveDate IN User TO DateTime.UtcNow
                    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
                    user.LastActiveDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                ...
            }
            ...
      }
      ...
```

*User.cs*

```
namespace Nemesys.Models
{
    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
       public DateTime LastActiveDate { get; set; }
       ...
    }
}
```

Just in case, this is how I set up the new user during Registration in
*Register.cshtml.cs*, but I highly doubt there is any issue with this as it seems to be displaying the set `DateTime.UtcNow` just fine.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new User {
                    ...
                    LastActiveDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                };
...
```

I am quite sure there is a quick way to do this but I'm quite new to C# and can't figure it out or find a related query on it online. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You must set user detail by write it to `AspNetUsers` table. You maybe need extend user entity (it is a popular practice), see https://www.freecodespot.com/blog/custom-identity-columns-in-aspdotnet-core/

For a specific case (in comment), record last log in time, you need extend `AspNetUsers`, by extend entity

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     public virtual DateTime? LastLoginTime { get; set; }
     public virtual DateTime? RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

See more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24618153/3728901

Comment: Hi, it already is a column in `AspNetUsers` (sorry for not making it clear) - [LastActiveDate column](https://imgur.com/I8mkMTZ), and everything related to it is set in `AppDBContext`. I am having difficulty accessing that column of the current user to set `LastActiveDate ` to current date, which would preferably be set as soon as user logs in.

Comment: I have edited the question to better reflect my issue, hope this helps in better understanding.