# How to update the LastLogin field in the AspNetUsers table

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have implemented razor view based identity in asp.net core 6. The logging works fine. However, whenever someone logs in, I want the LastLogin field in the AspNetUsers table to be updated with the login date. However, it always stays at  0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000. The following is the code by which the logging takes place in the Login.cshtml.cs page.

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.Email, Input.Password, 
Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");       
    return Redirect(URL);
}
```

I am new to asp.net core and identity. So, my apologies if it's a trivial question.

Comment: You will need to update it manually yourself.

Comment: You can try to  extend user object like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571034/asp-net-identity-record-user-registration-and-last-logged-on-time  .  Then  try `user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;`